# Why do unsigned int x = -1 and int y = ~0 have the same binary representation?

Tags: c, binary

In the following code segment what will be:

- the result of function
- value of x
- value of y

```
    {
         unsigned int x=-1;
         int y;
         y = ~0;
         if(x == y)
             printf("same");
         else
             printf("not same");
     }
```

```
a. same, MAXINT, -1
b. not same, MAXINT, -MAXINT
c. same , MAXUINT, -1
d. same, MAXUINT, MAXUINT
e. not same, MAXINT, MAXUINT
```

Can someone explain me how its works or can just explain the snippet??

I know it's about two's complement n etc..
What is the significance of MAXINT and -1 ?
It is because of unsigned int and int thing - am I right ?

Comment: The answer isn't A.

Comment: Shouldn't it be MAXUINT, not MAXUNIT?

Comment: Couldn't the answer also be (A) on a 32 bit system if this same program was run as is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you run this program, you will see that the answer a is *wrong* and c is the correct answer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main() {
    unsigned int x=-1;
    int y;
    y = ~0;
    if(x == y)
        printf("same\n");
        if(x==INT_MAX) printf("INT_MAX\n");
        if(x==UINT_MAX) printf("UINT_MAX\n");
    else
        printf("not same");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @shraddha: Unfortunately the C language leaves a lot unspecified so running the program on one particular implementation (even one  known to be 100% conforming) doesn't tell you what the language specifies. This is only one 'final' answer.

Answer (score 13):

`unsigned int x=-1;`

`1` is an integer literal and has type `int` (because it fits in an `int`). Unary `-` applied to an `int` causes no further promotion so `-1` is an `int` with value `-1`.

When converted to an `unsigned int` modulo 2^N arithmetic is used where N is the number of value bits in an `unsigned int`. `x` has the value 2^N - 1 which is `UINT_MAX` (What's `MAX_UNIT`?).

```
int y;
y = ~0;
```

Again `0` is type `int`, in C all the allowed representations of `int` must have all the value bits of an `int` representing 0 as 0. Again no promotion happens for unary `~` so `~0` is an `int` with all value bits being 1. What it's value is is implementation dependent but it is negative (the sign bit will be set) so definitely neither of `UINT_MAX` or `INT_MAX`. This value is stored in `y` unchanged.

```
if(x == y)
    printf("same");
else
    printf("not same");
```

In this comparison `y` will be converted to `unsigned int` in order to be compared with `x` which is already an `unsigned int`. As `y` has an implementation value, the value after conversion to `unsigned int` is still implementation defined (although the conversion itself is modulo 2^N and fully specified). The result of the comparison is still implementation defined.

So in conclusion:

> implementation defined, `UINT_MAX`, implementation defined

In practice on ones' complement:

> not same, `UINT_MAX`, -0 (aka 0)

sign plus magnitude:

> not same, `UINT_MAX`, `INT_MIN`

two's complement:

> same, `UINT_MAX`, -1

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that it actually depends on the implementation and the question as presented is somewhat flawed? I think the relevant part of the standard is [section 6.2.6.2 §2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf)(pdf)

Comment: +1 I did not realize that the signed integer implementation is *not* defined in the C standard. It can be *two's complement*, *one's complement* or *sign and magnitude*. This is something that needs to be taken in consideration (even though it is practically always two's complement).

Answer (score 9):

Its pretty easy.  The twos complement representation of -1 is 0xFFFFFFFF.  Hence that is what x contains.

The complement operator (~) flips all the bits.  So the complement of 0 is a 32-bit number with all the bits set to 1 or 0xFFFFFFFF.

Edit: As pointed out int he comments.  The answer is not A.  If it was then it would be saying 0x7FFFFFFF and 0xFFFFFFFF are the same.  They're not.  The real answer is C (Assuming MAXUNIT is a typo ;)).

Comment: yeah i know its about twos compliment may be my question ws wrong ,,
why in ans options they hav given MAXINT n -1 etc things ,,i dont understand the significance its obvious that they are same...bt they have three options saying same n what about other things with 
the options...plz tel me that

Comment: Doesn't that mean the correct answer should be c (assuming UNIT is supposed to be UINT)? That's what I would have said anyway.

Comment: okay is it coz -1 is unsigned so it gives MAXINT n as y is int it gives us -1??

Comment: I figured the compiler would complain about assigning -1 to an unsigned int, but it does compile - interesting.

Comment: @Darel in fact... C is C! You can map to asm more easier than any other language (asm apart!)... an assembler can't complain for, say "mov eax, -1" or "mov eax, FFFFFFFFh"... cpu can't distinguish... :D

Comment: if MAXUNIT is MAXUINT, I agree with @sepp2k !! it should be: same MAXUINT, -1

Answer (score 2):

It's because of [twos-complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement)

The flipping of the bits results in a bit pattern that matches -1

Comment: yeah i know its about twos compliment may be my question ws wrong ,,
why in ans options they hav given MAXINT n -1 etc things ,,i dont understand the significance its obvious that they are same...bt they have three options saying same n what about other things with the options....plz tel me that ..

Comment: I was not aware of the existance of MAXUNIT... as for MAXINT, the A) says MAXINT is as -1 (int), and you already know why, knowing the 2s technics. The two values (MAXINT, -1; MAXUNIT, -MAXUNIT) are the values being compared "effectively", I think. So, looking backward, even ignoring what MAXUNIT is, the answers must be the first, since MAXINT and -1 are the same and what you get from your program... (a bit tautological?)

Comment: my previous comment is wrong: MAXUINT is equal to -1. (being MAXUNIT indeed MAXUINT)

Answer (score 1):

Since in the first unsigned int, you put -1, but from the unsigned int point of view it is 0xFFFFFFFF (this is how negative integers are stored into a computer); in the second case the bitwise not does not look at the "kind" at all and "transform" 0 into 1 and viceversa, so all zeros of 0 becomes 1 (looking at bits), so you obtain 0xFFFFFFFF.

The next question is, why comparing an unsigned integer with a signed integer does not distinguish them? (numerically 4294967295 is not equal to -1 of course, even though their representation in a computer is the same). Indeed it could, but clearly C does not mandate such a distinction, and it is "natural", since processor aren't able to do it of their own (I am not sure about this last sentence being **always** true, ... but it is for most processor): to take into account this distinction in asm, you have to add extra code.

From the C point of view, you have to decide if to cast int into unsigned int, or signed int into unsigned int. But a negative number can't be cast into a unsigned one, of course, and on the other hand, an unsigned number could cause overflow (e.g. for 4294967295 you need a 64bit register (or a 33bit regster!) to be able to have it and still be able to calculate its negative value)...

So likely the most natural thing is to avoid strange casting, and permit a "cpu like" comparison, which in this case lead to 0xFFFFFFFF (-1 on 32 bit) compared to 0xFFFFFFFF (~0 on 32bit), which are the same, and more in genereal one can be considered as MAXUINT (the maximum unsigned integer that can be hold) and the other as -1. (Take a look at your machine `limits.h` include to check it)

Comment: Important comment: as said elsewhere, I agree with sepp2k, if MAXUNIT is indeed MAXUINT, since MAXUINT is 4294967295 (on a 32 bit machine) and MAXINT is indeed 2147483647, on 32 bit machine... , so C is the right one, not A

Comment: meta-comment on the comment: I made this comment and others before sepp2k posted his answer: I refer to his/her comments.