# Why does ~0 is -1?

Tags: javascript, math, binary

So as I was [reading about `~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#section_7),

> Performs the NOT operator on each bit.

So I tried:

```
 0 = 00000000000000000000000000000000

         so ~0 should be

~0 = 11111111111111111111111111111111
```

But when I tried, it returns `-1`. Isn't `11111111111111111111111111111111` is `4294967295` in decimal?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141163/why-do-unsigned-int-x-1-and-int-y-0-have-the-same-binary-representation

Comment: @copy - It is in `C` not JavaScript.

Comment: It's a very basic thing that applies to most programming languages. Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement or http://stackoverflow.com/a/3141181/1078067

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's interpreted as a signed integer, and in two's complement, an integer with all bits 1 is `-1`.

Comment: So when you turn `4294967295` into binary then turn it back into decimal it will become `-1`?

Comment: Possibly worth adding - in twos complement, all the bits have the same value they would for an unsigned value except for the most significant. That most significant bit (MSB) has it's value negated relative to the same bit in an unsigned value - e.g. for 32 bit integers, the MSB is worth -2147483648 for twos complement rather than +2147483648 for unsigned.

Comment: That depends on the used language and types, @Derek. If I remember Javascript's behaviour correctly, if you enter `4294967295`, it will be treated as a `number` and be represented internally as a `double`, so it won't be turned to `-1` automatically. But if you do bit operations on it, it will be converted to a (signed) 32-bit integer, and then the bit pattern is interpreted as `-1`.

Comment: There is no such thing as "turning" a value into binary -- binary is how everything is stored in a computer -- the rest is merely for our convenience. The bit about two's complement having the same bit values as they would on the positive side is incorrect for x86 processors, they are not'ed and one is added. Otherwise how could all bits set equal -1?

Answer (score 7):

Only if the type is unsigned. Signed integers use the topmost bit as a negation flag - and thus setting it to 1 results in a negative number. See [Two's Complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Answer (score 6):

A bit-pattern of all `1`s is `4294967295` for an unsigned integer, or a signed integer with more than *32-bits*. For a signed integer with *32-bits* represented as *two's complement* its `-1`.